# are these things "not... really related in any way"

Tags: discussion

> By pop philosophy, I suppose I mean wikipedia, this site, newspaper
> reports on the 20th century, opinions of the "masses" - with or
> without Marxism - in general, 'militant atheism' and so on. What do
> professional philosophers think of it, that it's amusing, dangerous,
> completely irrelevant?

I was quite insulted by the comment that followed this claim, which seemed to suggest I was so confused as to not bother the legendary minds of philosophy stackexchange. Guy needs to get a grip: the overlap is that are you not serious philosophers but pontificate on it in public.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is this in relation to? Where did that quotation come from?